# Spectrum of approximating Schrodinger operators

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $H = -\Delta + V$ be a Schrödinger a self-adjoint operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with core $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R^n})$, where $V \in L^2_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Let's define for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ the following operators:
$$
H_k = -\Delta + V \chi_{ \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n : |V(x) | \le n\}}
$$

Is it true that the spectrum $\sigma (H_k)$ is contained in the spectrum $\sigma(H)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $V$ is negative and $H$ has a few discrete eigenvalues ("bound states"). You could choose $V$ so that the difference $H - H_k$ is a small perturbation, producing a small shift in the eigenvalues, so they do not coincide.

Comment: Right. Thanks a lot! But is it true that all the spectra $\sigma (H_k)$ are uniformly bounded from below by a constant?

Comment: @Onil90 What if V has an infinite number of potential wells of increasing depth?